# Material UI select jumps to the top of the page

Tags: reactjs, iframe, material-ui

I am using material ui select component. When the page is embedded as part of the iframe, I am seeing a jump to the top of the page whenever I interact with the select component. I've tried adding `getContentAnchorEl: null,` as part of the MenuProps but it does not work

Comment: I need to see the code to help you

Comment: @mdmundo same for me, the sample is here https://dmitryy.github.io/iframe-resizer-react-mui/ (I thought it's because of iframe-resizer but if I use regular iframe it is still jumps to the top of the page)

1. src of the iframe page - https://github.com/dmitryy/iframe-resizer-react-mui/blob/main/src/App.tsx
2. src of the content page - https://github.com/dmitryy/iframe-resizer-react-content/blob/main/src/App.tsx

Comment: `getContentAnchorEl` has been removed from MUI 5.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<Select 
MenuProps={{ autoFocus: false,
             disableAutoFocusItem: true,
             disableEnforceFocus: true,
             disableAutoFocus: true
           }} ...
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer for MUI 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after a few days of trying to fix it, and trying everything here and on stack Overflow , i found a way to fix the jumping-up issue :

```
MenuProps={{disableScrollLock: true,}}
```

hope it gonna help someone

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. This is just a note to help you improve your answers. To help future users better understand your answer please provide an explanation with your code blocks. For example, you could explain why your solution works, or how your approach is different from other answers.